# How can I call from my app in Android?

Tags: android

Hi guys I'm new on android and I'm trying to do a call after pushing an ImageButton on my Activity and I did this snippet as I find on other questions on stackoverflow.

```
icotelefono.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //icotelefono.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        String url = "tel:3348292536";
        Intent intent_phone = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent_phone);
    }
});
```

but when I click on the button the app crash and I don't know why, because when this snippet is in the MainActivity that extend fragmentactivity all goes well. But when it is in the Activity where it should be that extend Activity the app crash. Other info: I already have the permissions in the manifest.

**[Edit]**
Logcat:

```
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080): Process: com.example.findmyclients, PID: 4080
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3493)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3735)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3703)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at com.example.findmyclients.Hide_Unhide$1.onClick(Hide_Unhide.java:81)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-09 17:20:34.846: E/AndroidRuntime(4080):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 17:20:36.391: I/Process(4080): Sending signal. PID: 4080 SIG: 9
```

Thank you all.

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I will write logcat output with a Edit in some seconds

Comment: @Tanis.7x here you are

Comment: what is `Hide_Unhide` ?

Comment: the name of the class where this snippet is

Comment: put a break point before `onClick()` in `Hide_Unhide` and then debug.

Comment: @Rustam it give me a null pointer exception with a try catch

Comment: some code will be their in `try` block check which variable is null?

Comment: No variables are null but in my opinion there is a problem with the View. :/ I have some problems with view and similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62767/discussion-between-pierpaolo-ercoli-and-rustam).

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thanks for catching that. Skimmed the log too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your manifest the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: the snippet is working when extending FragmentActivity, so it's not the problem.

Comment: @mithrop It only work with a FragmentActivity class or if with a fragment activity class work the problem is not in the snippet?

Comment: no. I said that the "permission" is not the problem. jony17 gave a false hint

Answer (score 0):

The occurrence of an NPE within the system-provided code implementing the parent Activity class suggests that you may be using an improperly-initialized instance of a your subclass of Activity.   Your call stack manages to descend several methods into the code of android.app.Activity, before failing at the first one which tries to actually do work.

Examining some of the code from a slightly different version:

```
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {
    if (mParent == null) {
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
            mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
                this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
                intent, requestCode, options);
```

We see attempts to call methods of instance field objects such as `mInstrumentation`, and it is probably one of these which is null.

You write:

> when this snippet is in the MainActivity that extend fragmentactivity all goes well. But when it is in the Activity where it should be that extend Activity the app crash.

This suggests that you may be improperly trying to create an instance of your custom Activity class using `new`.  The result of that would be an improperly initialized instance, with many critical fields still null.

**You cannot get a working instance of an Activity using `new`, but only by using an `Intent` to ask the system to create one for you**.

Comment: I make an error it was... "when it is in the Activity where it should be that extend Application the app crash", sorry

Comment: An Activity cannot extend Application!

Comment: sorry again, today it's not my day :P .. a class extend application

Comment: Your stack trace shows that you are doing this from a class which extends android.app.Activity, not android.app.Application.  If your stack trace does not show your actual experiment, **then edit your question and post the stack trace of what you are actually doing**.